# How can I get a detailed table list in R?

Tags: r, statistics, sas

Been using SAS for 6 years and migrating across to R. I used to use proc contents to get a healthy description of a table, a characteristic and a data type.

Using `str(tableName)` I can see the type but not the vector position in a data frame.

Using `name(tableName)` I can see the names and positions of the vectors but not the type.

Using `summary(tableName)` I can see the quantiles/category but not the type easily or vector position.

Is there a way I can just get a list of
Name vectorPosition type min max avg med [..]

Comment: ?fivenum might be what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to call a function 
on each column of the data.frame,
and compute all the quantities you want in that function.

```
summary_text <- function(d) {
  do.call(rbind, lapply( d, function(u)
    data.frame(
      Type    = class(u)[1],
      Min     = if(is.numeric(u)) min(   u, na.rm=TRUE) else NA,
      Mean    = if(is.numeric(u)) mean(  u, na.rm=TRUE) else NA,
      Median  = if(is.numeric(u)) median(u, na.rm=TRUE) else NA,
      Max     = if(is.numeric(u)) max(   u, na.rm=TRUE) else NA,
      Missing = sum(is.na(u))
    )    
  ) )
}
summary_text(iris)
```

But I personnally prefer to look at the data graphically:
the following function will draw a histogram and a quantile-quantile plot
for each numeric variable, and a barplot for each factor,
on a single page. If you have 20 to 30 variables, it should remain usable.

```
summary_plot <- function(d, aspect=1) {
  # Split the screen: find the optimal number of columns 
  # and rows to be as close as possible from the desired aspect ratio.
  n <- ncol(d)
  dx <- par()$din[1]
  dy <- par()$din[2]
  f <- function(u,v) {
    if( u*v >= n && (u-1)*v < n && u*(v-1) < n ) {
      abs(log((dx/u)/(dy/v)) - log(aspect))
    } else { 
      NA 
    }
  }
  f <- Vectorize(f)
  r <- outer( 1:n, 1:n, f )
  r <- which( r == min(r,na.rm=TRUE), arr.ind=TRUE )
  r <- r[1,2:1]

  op <- par(mfrow=c(1,1),mar=c(2,2,2,2))
  plot.new()
  if( is.null( names(d) ) ) { names(d) <- 1:ncol(d) }
  ij <- matrix(seq_len(prod(r)), nr=r[1], nc=r[2], byrow=TRUE)
  for(k in seq_len(ncol(d))) {
    i <- which(ij==k, arr.ind=TRUE)[1]
    j <- which(ij==k, arr.ind=TRUE)[2]
    i <- r[1] - i + 1
    f <- c(j-1,j,i-1,i) / c(r[2], r[2], r[1], r[1] )
    par(fig=f, new=TRUE)
    if(is.numeric(d[,k])) { 
      hist(d[,k], las=1, col="grey", main=names(d)[k], xlab="", ylab="")
      o <- par(fig=c(
          f[1]*.4  + f[2]*.6,
          f[1]*.15 + f[2]*.85,
          f[3]*.4  + f[4]*.6,
          f[3]*.15 + f[4]*.85
        ), 
        new=TRUE,
        mar=c(0,0,0,0)
      )
      qqnorm(d[,k],axes=FALSE,xlab="",ylab="",main="")
      qqline(d[,k])
      box()
      par(o)
    } else {
      o <- par(mar=c(2,5,2,2))
      barplot(table(d[,k]), horiz=TRUE, las=1, main=names(d)[k])
      par(o)
    }
  }
  par(op)
}
summary_plot(iris)
```

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you might be looking for something like `describe()`, from the `Hmisc` package.  My recollection is that Frank Harrel (the package's author) was a long-time SAS programmer who came over to the R world fairly early on. The style of the summaries that `describe()` provides certainly seem to reflect that computing genealogy:

```
library(Hmisc)
describe(cars) # for example
cars 

 2  Variables      50  Observations
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
speed 
      n missing  unique    Mean     .05     .10     .25     .50     .75     .90 
     50       0      19    15.4     7.0     8.9    12.0    15.0    19.0    23.1 
    .95 
   24.0 

          4 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 22 23 24 25
Frequency 2 2 1 1  3  2  4  4  4  3  2  3  4  3  5  1  1  4  1
%         4 4 2 2  6  4  8  8  8  6  4  6  8  6 10  2  2  8  2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dist 
      n missing  unique    Mean     .05     .10     .25     .50     .75     .90 
     50       0      35   42.98   10.00   15.80   26.00   36.00   56.00   80.40 
    .95 
  88.85 

lowest :   2   4  10  14  16, highest:  84  85  92  93 120 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know that package yet!

Comment: @Rappster -- Glad to give it some publicity. It's a sprawling and somewhat random collection of Harrel's miscellaneous tools, but there are some definite goodies in there. (`contents()` is another `Hmisc` function that's worth a look-see.) I haven't used `Hmisc` much since my early days with R, but back then I used both it and Harrel's `Design` package quite a bit. (Checking just now, I see that `Design` has long since been removed from CRAN, and is only available from the archives).

Comment: `design` was superseded by `rms` (for "Regression Modeling Strategies", the associated book, which is also well worth some time investment)

Comment: Thanks a bunch @BenBolker. I was kind of aghast to find it missing (if that's possible) , and am very glad to know where it went.

Comment: That's a fantastic function but it is not easy to see what position dist is in the data frame (It's obviously 2 but I am looking at hundreds of vectors). It also doesn't easily tell me the type. Thank you for your help though really appreciate it.

Comment: It is possible to include the result in a LaTeX file (with `latex(describe(d))`): it is then much easier to distinguish between the variables.

Answer (score 2):

This is really "quick 'n' dirty", but if I understood you correctly, this is kind of what you're after.

As an example, I took the info returned by `summary()` and simply added information about `class` and `mode` for each data frame column. I'm not really familiar with the `table` class in R, hence formatting is really off.

```
df <- data.frame(
    a=1:5,
    b=rep(TRUE, 5),
    c=letters[1:5]
)

mySummary <- function(x, ...) {
    out <- NULL
    for (ii in 1:ncol(x)) {
        temp <- list(
            c(paste("Class:", class(x[,ii])), paste("Mode:", mode(x[,ii])),
            c(a[,ii]))
        )
        names(temp) <- names(x)[ii]
        out <- c(out, temp)
    }   
    out 
}

> mySummary(df)
$a

"Class: integer"  "Mode: numeric"    "Min.   :1  "    "1st Qu.:2  " 

   "Median :3  "    "Mean   :3  "    "3rd Qu.:4  "    "Max.   :5  " 

$b

"Class: logical"  "Mode: logical" "Mode:logical  " "TRUE:5        " 

"NA's:0        "               NA               NA               NA 

$c

"Class: factor" "Mode: numeric"         "a:1  "         "b:1  "         "c:1  " 

        "d:1  "         "e:1  "              NA
```

You might want to check out how the `summary()` method for class `data.frame` is defined and then go ahead and tweak it to fit your needs.

Find out which methods are defined for `summary()`

```
methods("summary")

> methods("summary")
 [1] summary.aov             summary.aovlist         summary.aspell*        
 [4] summary.connection      summary.data.frame      summary.Date           
 [7] summary.default         summary.ecdf*           summary.factor         
[10] summary.glm             summary.infl            summary.lm             
[13] summary.loess*          summary.manova          summary.matrix         
[16] summary.mlm             summary.nls*            summary.packageStatus* 
[19] summary.PDF_Dictionary* summary.PDF_Stream*     summary.POSIXct        
[22] summary.POSIXlt         summary.ppr*            summary.prcomp*        
[25] summary.princomp*       summary.srcfile         summary.srcref         
[28] summary.stepfun         summary.stl*            summary.table          
[31] summary.tukeysmooth*   

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

Here's a way to get to the code

```
summary.data.frame
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you just want:

```
lapply(tableName, class)
```

It's possible that you might *think* you want:

```
lapply(tableName, typeof)
```

... but `typeof` returns only the storage mode which is less informative, becauseunctions in R are dispatched on the 'class' of variables.